# Keeping upper or lower case while performing str_replace [ PHP 8.0 ]

Tags: php, html, search, str-replace

I am presently giving the command:

```
<?php echo str_ireplace( $url['word']['word'] , ( '<strong>' . $url['word']['word'] . '</strong>' ) , $url['word']['question'] ); ?></p>
```

I am using this in a "Word Of The Day" section of my web site.  The purpose is that the word being used gets displayed in bold when viewed on the web page.  For example:

```
What is the next **Aspiration** in your life you are working towards?
```

What I am really wanting to do is find a better way of inserting the `<strong>` tag around the word of the day.  Right at the moment I have stored the words all with capitalization.  I am hesitant to include HTML in the actual table so I can format this appropriately depending on any programming changes in the future.  From the above example **A**spiration is capitalized.  But the "question" in the database is:

```
What is the next aspiration in your life you are working towards?
```

My database table structure is:

```
reference bigint
word text
question text
add_date timestamp with time zone
membership_reference
```

Is there a better way to add the `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check for word boundaries, not just any arbitrary match. Note what happens if your word is `aspiration` and your sentence is:

```
What is the next exaspiration in your life you are working towards?
```

Then you get a partial match:

```
What is the next ex<strong>aspiration<strong> in your life you are working towards?
```

To avoid this, you can use the `\b` regex pattern, and to make it case insensitive, you can use the `/i` modifier. Then, to preserve the case of the replaced word, capture the matched text with parens and replace with the matched text placeholder `\1` instead of whatever casing the original source word had:

```
preg_replace('/\b(' . $word . ')\b/i', '<strong>\1</strong>', $question);
```

This yields:

```
This <strong>aspiration</strong> is lowercase.
<strong>Aspiration</strong> remains caps here.
But exaspiration does not get tagged.
```

I'd also recommend using something like `<span class="word-of-the-day">` instead of `<strong>` -- then you can change your styling in CSS and you don't have to edit source code.